# Specifying 'public' in function declarations

Tags: php

I have a little question.

What is the difference between

```
interface SomeInterface {
   public function foo();
}
```

and

```
interface SomeInterface {
   function foo();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically they are the same, if there's no specified access modifier, functions are public by default.

Answer (score 2):

The letter 'e' in the name :) Basically there is no difference, because if you don't specify the visibility of a method it is public by default.

Comment: Actually it is the most appropriate answer to the question :) +1